# try catch reset my variables to the an original value even if it is a global variable

Tags: java, android

I need to get the size of a listarray that is used inside a try catch because I want some data from a `JsonObject`, well here is the code, could you help to get `CantidadCirculares.length` out of that block

private void setList() {

```
        StringRequest GG = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONObject datos = jsonObject.getJSONObject("dataFromWs");
                    JSONArray CantidadCirculares = datos.getJSONArray("id_circular");
                    message=datos.getString("message");
                    for (int i = 0; i < CantidadCirculares.length(); i++) {

                        id_circular = datos.getJSONArray("id_circular").get(i).toString();
                        titulo = datos.getJSONArray("titulo").get(i).toString();
                        descripcion = datos.getJSONArray("descripcion").get(i).toString();
                        contenido = datos.getJSONArray("contenido").get(i).toString();
                        fecha = datos.getJSONArray("fecha").get(i).toString();
                        mes = datos.getJSONArray("mes").get(i).toString();
                        dia = datos.getJSONArray("dia").get(i).toString();
                        publicado = datos.getJSONArray("publicado").get(i).toString();


                        CircularList.add((new CircularVo(dia,mes,titulo,descripcion,id_circular)));
                        CircularList.add(new CircularVo("20", "Mayo", "Título circular lorem", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lacus sit amet ipsum pharetra.", "1"));

                        /*Circulares.put("id",id_circular);
                        Circulares.put("title",titulo);
                        Circulares.put("desc",descripcion);
                        Circulares.put("contenido",contenido);
                        Circulares.put("fecha",fecha);
                        Circulares.put("month",mes);
                        Circulares.put("day",dia);
                        Circulares.put("publicado",publicado);
                        mientras.add(i,Circulares);*/
                    }

                    x=tamaño(CantidadCirculares.length());

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    System.out.println("hola");
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(CircularActivity.this, "No es posible actualizar ahora", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    Toast.makeText(CircularActivity.this, String.valueOf(x), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(CircularActivity.this, String.valueOf(x), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(GG);

        for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            CircularList.add(new CircularVo(String.valueOf(i),"Mayo", "Título circular lorem", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse id lacus sit amet ipsum pharetra.", "1"));
        }
}
```

I know that `x` maybe is not showed here but it is declared as a global variable with an original value = `0`, but ending the try block the value came back to `0`

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint at the line where x gets the value of the length of the list to see if it is executed?

Comment: An exception handler does not "put back" anything. The exception could be thrown _before_ `x=...` is executed. That would be an explanation why the value is unchanged.

Comment: Yes i tried the breakpoint but it is executed, after the try block ends x take the original value

Answer (score 0):

This line `x=tamaño(CantidadCirculares.length());` calls a method named `tamaño()`  
If you want the size of the list `CantidadCirculares` then you must change it to:  
`x=CantidadCirculares.length();`

Comment: I already have done that, the value came back to the original value

Comment: Edit your posted code with the correct line.  In your comment you say that you have already put a breakpoint. So immediately after the breakpoint does x contain the right value or not?